# Remodeling contractor went broke, didn't deliver services paid for - deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, bankruptcy

In spring of 2021, I hired a remodeling contractor in Illinois and paid him progress payments totaling about 90% of the contract price.  Then he went broke, leaving a mess, which turned out to be less than 50% complete.

Also, the actual cost to complete the work with a 2nd contractor was substantially greater than the original quote, giving credit for the work that was completed (he underbid the project).

The contractor does not appear to have filed for bankruptcy, and did not respond to registered letters presenting the claim of debt against the company.  It appears to have ceased operations, and an attorney estimated based on the cost and likelihood of collection that it was not worth pursuing.

Can I deduct the amount of money I paid that was never completed against my taxes (as a bad debt, or otherwise..), which is at least $15k, depending on how it's calculated (he owes me according to his own quote for non-delivery, and then the 2nd contractor's price to do the remaining work was much higher that our original bid, so two separate issues).

Comment: You already have an attorney - why don't you ask them?

Comment: Was the work going to be a business or personal expense?

Comment: It was a personal expense.  Atty doesn't do tax advice.  I did find an IRS reference that said something like 'Paid deposits that were not completed or refunded' would be deductible, and I didn't see any reference to business income.